# Android customize AppCompat ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have seen multiple threads on this but I am unable to find the solution to my problem. I want to create a custom action bar so to begin I just tried something simple like just a custom color:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Then in my `Manifest` I have:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

My `MainActivity` also `extends ActionBarActivity`

I was getting an error saying that I need to apply `Theme.AppCompat` to my `Activity` but I am no longer getting that error. My application compiles and runs but the action bar is just standard black, not red (#FF0000).

Eventually I want to make my action bar transparent but I figured I would get this sorted out first. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html), for retro-compatibility, you should use `actionBarStyle` along with `android:actionBarStyle`:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want flexibility use Toolbar instead of ActionBar. I dont think you can make the default action bar transpatent, and you can achieve that with Toolbar. Read more here http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 0):

With new AppCompat-v7 (v21) ActionBar style's properties need to refer to the app namespace, that is without `android:` prefix.